# org-mode russian filename pdf export

Tags: org-export, latex

Is there a way to make pdf-export of files named in russian?

I use xelatex which is set up like:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

latin named files are ok to be exported, but if I name it `Документ.org` then there is an error:

`*messages*`

```
org-latex-compile: PDF file ./Документ.pdf wasn't produced
```

`*Org PDF LaTeX Output*`

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `'"c:/Users/user/org/work/Документ.tex"''.
<*> .../work/Докуметн.tex"'

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> .../work/Документ.tex"'

No pages of output.
Transcript written on .//texput.log.
```

Comment: It's a [latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53644/what-are-the-allowed-characters-in-filenames) [thing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59367/allowable-filenames-for-source-files).

Comment: I tried the same thing on OSX -- and it works. So it is windows make the difference. I guess I have to use ascii then.

Comment: You are right.  Thanks for reporting that.  Your filename also works on my GNU/Linux.  I think windows might still be running in `latin-1`...